# Parsing ridiculous json string in php

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest

I am querying a restful web service (clickbank) I am able to send and receive my requests but (embarrassingly enough), I am having trouble parsing the results to make them readable. When I select XML as the return format what I get back is a 97,000 character long string(yay var_dump).... with no spaces in it... and no delimiter (such as ',' or '/', or even '<', or '>'), separating the values. So, I have selected JSON as the return format. I have been able to decode this herculean string using json_decode and I have deciphered that what I am getting back is an array of 100 objects, each object has 30 vars (ala get_object_vars), but some of these vars are themselves arrays of objects. Forgive my ignorance but any ideas on how I can parse this so that it's in the realm of readable? By the way, I am currently trying my hand at PHP (as that is what we use at the shop where I work). I am mildly retarded when it comes to using Eclipse PDT so any suggestions would be welcome....
P.S. I have the following function that has been helpful in determining what the hay is going on but it still doesn't separate things out like I want

```
function getInfo($datum) {  
    switch (gettype($datum)) {

        case "object":
            $GLOBALS['counts']++;
            //var_dump($datum);
            echo "<hr>";
            //$members = get_object_vars($datum);
            //getInfo($members);
            break;
        case "array":
                foreach($datum as $v) {
                    getInfo($v);
                }
                //var_dump($datum);
                break;
        default:
            echo "<div>$datum</div>";                
    }
}
```

This is a bit of a side question here: down at the bottom of my snippet (see the default condition of switch statement), $datum WAS part of an array (before it was passed back into the function at the final depth of recursion here). Is there a way to elaborate that echo statement so that it shows whatever it's key was? I'm trying to word this in the least confusing way possible, but if that value (probably a string) is the value of some index of an associative array, but without me having to specify any of the possible names of the arrays? (think in_array but without the $haystack argument)

Comment: `997,000 character long string`  Isn't that too long a response from a web service?

Comment: Ok `97,000 character long string` Isn't that too long a response from a web service? Sorry don't mind but if a web service is returning you that long of a string as an API response, there is something wrong. I would never use that api

Comment: couldn't you store the array key as a separate variable and pass that in as well?

Comment: its a very long JSON encoded string, each element/object that is returned has a long description, and the fields that are returned have long descriptions, and since it is user information, some of the user entered information is LONG (think addresses and the like)
@ambe5960, good call, sleep deprivation was getting me bad